# Is e4rat is still(2016) faster than ureadahead on HDDs?

Tags: boot

*Since I have HDD and I want to reduce my boot time*, I am deciding to move from **ureadahead to e4rat**,

But I have a doubt since e4rat have not been developed after 2012-05-03 according to [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e4rat/files/), but If you look for ureadahead thing is similar, seems to be no any new major releases after 2009-11-29 according to launchpad, but Ubuntu 16.04 also still uses ureadahead 0.100.0-19.(according to launchpad). I found that e4rat was faster comparatively to ureadahead in 2010-2013 period(according to old posts). Is e4rat still faster than ureadhead? or is there any new ureadahead versions which is faster than e4rat(that I have missed)?

Answer (score 5):

Let's look what does the beasts do

- **ureadahead** only caches frequently used files, and reads them into RAM on boot.
- **e4rat** consist of different tools, one is `e4rat-realloc`, which moves around frequently used files so, that their blocks would lay close one to another, reducing movement path of a magnetic head of HDD for loading those files.

  And `e4rat-preload` tool, which does *(upon added to kernel parameters)* the same job as **ureadahead**. Interestingly, [Archlinux wiki mentions possibility](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/e4rat#Who_benefits.2C_who_does_not) to use **e4rat** and **ureadahead** at the same time, though without details. They perhaps meant using **ureadahead** instead of `e4rat-preaload`.

Hence for HDDs **e4rat** would always be faster than **ureadahead** is. For SSDs, for their random access time is the same as for adjacent blocks, re-fragmentation of files makes no sense. Hence the only tools touching perfomance are `e4rat-preload` and `ureadahead`, and for their job is the same, the perfomance would be the same too.

**NB**: due to SSDs being fast, **ureadahead** boosts perfomance not that much there. This led to discussion between systemd developers, who're using primarily SSDs nowadays. As it's useful anyway, they asked if anybody wanted to take maintainership for its analog **systemd-readahead**. [Nobody stood up for, and so it was removed](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-August/022002.html) from the systemd. So, I'd expect that development of **ureadahead** and **e4rat** would slow down too, if it isn't already.